# 2d ParticleSystem batching problem

Tags: unity, particles, batching

I have multiple `ParticleSystems` with `TextureSheetAnimation` pointing to the same texture, using different offsets/rows to choose different textures.

They seem to batch with each other, but they're also being split by Unity into multiple batches in a strange manner.

Here's a `Frame Debugger` view:

[image]

These 4 Draw Dynamic are on the same atlas, using `Mobile/ParticlesAdditive` shader.

The reason of breaking batching is:

> Objects have different batching keys. This is usually caused by using
>   different vertex streams on ParticleSystems or by mixing Lines and
>   Trails, or by mixing lit and unlit geometry.

All of the `ParticleSystems` have a simple setup, some `Color Over Lifetime`, some `Velocity Over Lifetime` etc.

The strange thing is that `Unity` breaks batching like it makes one batch, puts half of the stars and half of the smokes into that, and then, makes another batch from these two.

So they do batch, and the don't o.O

I couldn't find and help on the web about this issue. 
I'd be glad for help.